# Advice regarding LINQ query for filtering collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<T>` of `Customers` that contains information like: Name, Product, Note, Booking Date, and UnreadMessage.

My goal is to filter customers using these fields and using AND operator but what's troubling me is when there is a field that is not used for filtering.

For example, an assistant will look for a customer name with a specific product. I could have a LINQ query that will look like this.

```
var a = Customers.Where(x => x.name.Contains("someone") && x.product.Contains("nike"));
```

Another example is, it will look for a customer with, with a specific product, with some note

```
var a = Customers.Where(x => x.name.Contains("someone") && x.product.Contains("nike") && x.note.Contains("some note"));
```

Another example, it will look for a product and booking date
    var a = Customers.Where(x => x.product.Contains("someone") && x.bookingdate=DateTime.Now);

I hope you notice how many differenct queries I will write for this kind of filtering.

Name, product, note, booking date, or unread messages only

- name and product
- name and note
- name and booking date
- name and unread messages
- product and note
- product and booking date
- etc etc etc etc

I am writing an Windows tablet application by the way so DataTable and LINQ Dyanmics are not possible where I can just write a string expression.

I am aksing for an advice and help how to solve this kind of filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not *combine* `Where`?

```
var result = Customers
  .Where(item => (null == name) || item.name.Contains(name))
  .Where(item => (null == product) || item.product.Contains(product))
  .Where(item => (null == note) || item.note.Contains(note))
  ...
```

So if you don't want to filter out by any parameter (`name`, `product`, etc.) just set it to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just build your statement dynamically. if this is `linq to sql` you will benefit from simpler execution plans with this approach:

```
public class test
{
    public string name;
    public string lastname;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<test>
        {
            new test{name = "john", lastname = "smith"}
        };

        string fname = "aa";
        string lname = "sm";


        var select = list.Select(c=>c);

        if (fname != null)
            select = select.Where(c => c.name.Contains(fname));

        if (lname != null)
            select = select.Where(c => c.lastname.Contains(lname));

        var result = select.ToList();
    }

}
```

Comment: In your screenshot you are selecting `ToList`. Note that I am not doing that. I am just building statements first and executing it once. Look for deferred execution.

Comment: yes, mine is not optimize because I have to convert it into a list on each query.